# SSRS - Calculated field using column from other DataSet in Matrix (cross-tab)

Tags: matrix, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix

I have several DataSets in an SSRS report. How can I use a summed matrix (crosstab) column from one DataSet in a formula of another DataSet with the same data fields (just different selection criteria (categories differ)). When I specify that field in the other DataSet, it only gives me First every time (I did not use First()); it does not automatically move them with the crosstabs in the second DataSet.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this in SSRS 2008. This capability is first available in SSRS 2008 R2. Depending on how you use the data in the report layout, you might be able to use the ReportItems collection to get a value. For example, you can use the contents of Textbox1 with a field in a different dataset (field called MyColumn1) in an expression like this:

```
=ReportItems!Textbox1.Value + Fields!MyColumn1.Value
```

The ReportItems collection uses the value of a textbox after the page is rendered, so you get the result only and not the raw data so you'd have to be using raw data.

Comment: It appears the functionality may be the "Lookup" function: http://blog.datainspirations.com/2010/03/19/sql-server-2008-r2-reporting-services-look-up-look-down-look-all-around-part-i/

Comment: The functionality in 2008 R2 is called the "Lookup" function: http://blog.datainspirations.com/2010/03/19/sql-server-2008-r2-reporting-services-look-up-look-down-look-all-around-part-i/ (my issue/fix was needing a FIRST() in front of the result).